# How to display visualization in Spotfire based on specified row count by date?

Tags: spotfire

I have this visualization in Spotfire, if I only want to show date which rowcount has >= 20000, how to do it in Spotfire?

[image: rowcount_by_date]

Answer (score 0):

If you want row count >= 20000, you can easily achieve this in the bar chart. Following are the steps:

- Right-click on the visualization,
- Select Value Axis,
- In the Range input tab, hardcode Min: to 20000 and leave the Maximum blank (this way you will get all data for rowcount >=20000.

Screenshot attached. 
[image]